# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) after ng build

Tags: angular, angular7

I have my angular project working well on local. To put it on web server, I have created its build through `ng build` command on terminal which does not produce any error. And when I uploaded the build on server it does not load and gives the error in console for each css and js file that :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

I have corrected the url manually after that it started giving me the error : 
`Cannot match any routes`. URL Segment: 'bikeriding'. Can anyone guide my why is this happening or what I doing wrong.

I have already included `<base href='/'>` in index.html.

Comment: Where did you upload it? On which server? Which URL do you use to access your application?

Comment: Try `--deployUrl` options, https://angular.io/cli/build#options

Comment: It looks like you host your project in some folder. Can you please confirm what is URL you are looking?

Comment: <base href='/'> means that all scripts and resources are under domain, like example.com/script.js, mush safer is when you set './'